# js, jquery image to JSON -> JSON to image

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, image, base64

I am probably puting a bad query to google however i can not find proper solution.

I have an mobile app (client) that would allow admin to load images from server. Because all the data from server comes via JSON file, my idea is convert on server side an image to json object (ie with help of base64). Using this solution i might get multiple images and additional data in one JSON file. Later i would inject b64 encrypted image to image via javascript in mobile app. 
I can also use jquery.

The questions are:

- do i need encrypt image to base64 before changing it to json? (i'd do that via php). i guess i need to do this because of escape characters in pure image files.
- how to decrypt from base64 to json/string variable in javascript/jquery?
- how to put binary image (decrypted from base64) to an image. Ie vie `var img = new Image()`

Any answer to this questions would be appreciated.

Or maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: Are the images not in a public directory? Meaning could you not just send in your JSON response the URL to the image instead of trying to send a base64 encoded string of it

Comment: As for actually using base64, you can just create a [data url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) with the base64 string and use that as the src

Comment: I believe part of your challenge looking for solutions is that you're looking for the word "encoded" not "encrypted". that should help. Patrick Evans comment above is also correct. you can just use the data url

Comment: @Patrick Evans - yes, images may be opened as pure png/jpg in browser if you know proper url, however i want them to be downloaded to mobile in case of mobile up would be without internet connection
JeffWoodard - indeed - encoded instead of encrypted. you mean data url with canvas? or other solution?